# how to perform login with complete validation using Rest Api in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to Build an Application in React native i have to perform Login User Authentication using Rest `Api` . Because i am new to React native i am not able to understand how to perform this action can any body help. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Currently i just created a layout

Comment: but don't know how to proceed

Comment: try using fetch or axios

Comment: please suggest a way to write code for it or suggest a sample code please

Answer (score 1):

React Native provides the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) for your networking needs. Fetch will seem familiar if you have used XMLHttpRequest or other networking APIs before. You may refer to MDN's guide on Using Fetch for additional information.

**Making requests**

In order to fetch content from an arbitrary URL, just pass the URL to fetch:

```js
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/mydata.json');
```

example.js

```js
// Example POST method implementation:

postData('http://example.com/answer', {answer: 42})
  .then(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))) // JSON-string from `response.json()` call
  .catch(error => console.error(error));

function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  // Default options are marked with *
    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: 'cors', // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
        cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
        credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
        referrer: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *client
        body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
.then(response => console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(response)))
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}
```